# Customize Report filters: 'Invalid date'

Tags: reporting

In both sandbox and production, no report can be customized or created as all date filters or date entries read as `invalid date`. Locale is US English

**Fails - new or customize any report**
[image]

Also - If you select a date from the date picker, no date is populated (or is invisible)

**Works - run existing reports**
[image]

Existing reports will execute and their date filters can be changed from the Report page but they can't be customized; no new reports can be created.

Looks like a SFDC bug to me.

Anyone else seen this?

> UPDATE - Now a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Y77AAE) - has nothing to do with Fiscal year change. I removed all refs to fiscal year in OP
>
> UPDATE 2 - Now fixed see [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Y77AAE) - a rather rapid SFDC fix I might say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's just a bug they've introduced as part of their recent upgrades.  If you clear both of the dates reading "invalid date" and then click "Run Report" they re-populate properly, as you say, in the report itself...  My advice would be to set dates to "Custom" and "null" "null" then run your report then modify the dates at that time before saving.  It's more cumbersome for sure, but it will at least let you run reports in the meantime...

Comment: Nathan -- are you saying this is happening to you as well? Not related to fiscal year change?

Comment: Completely unrelated to fiscal year change... Just editing a report that worked a few weeks ago led to the same error messages you screenshot above...

Comment: you are so right - i checked some other orgs and they exhibit same issue. SFDC Support lines must be ringing off the hook now.

Answer (score 0):

WE are experiencing the same issue. You can change the dates on the "Run Report" page but not the "Customize" page.

Comment: Graham - this is not an answer; as you can see it is now a Known Issue and you should indicate it affects you on that page